# AS3 game development: attack movements not following suit of movement direction

Tags: actionscript-3, controls, game-physics

I'm making a top-down RPG style game, very much a throwback to zelda.  This is my code for the movement controls based on keyboard controls.  The movement itself is pretty solid, no stutter-key syndrome, all animations are triggered correctly.

However, when the attack button (SPACE in this case) is pressed it triggers the appropriate frame but when the key is released the corresponding frame is still visible, until another direction key is pressed.  So, when you attack it looks like he keeps his sword extended until another movement is made, and so on. This should only happen when the key is held down not when simply pressed. This is not the expected result.  The result I'm looking for is an attack that triggers every time the key is pressed, creating the normal buttondown=attacking, buttonup = not attacking.

The attacks and movement now are based on a variable moving:int = 4; That way I can switch the attack position to the corresponding movement direction.

Any ideas on how to correct this issue?

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent; 

character.stop(); 

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPress);// when key is pressed
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyRelease);//when key is released
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MainLoop);

var moving:int = 4;
var movingDown:Boolean = false;
var movingUp:Boolean = false;
var movingRight:Boolean = false;
var movingLeft:Boolean = false;


function onKeyPress(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{ 
   switch (e.keyCode) 
     { 
        case Keyboard.DOWN : movingDown = true; moving = 1; break;
        case Keyboard.UP : movingUp = true; moving = 2; break; 
        case Keyboard.RIGHT : movingRight = true; moving = 3; break; 
        case Keyboard.LEFT : movingLeft = true; moving = 4; break;
        case Keyboard.SPACE : handleAttack();  break;
      }           
 } 

 function onKeyRelease(e:KeyboardEvent):void
 {
    switch (e.keyCode)  
  { 
     case Keyboard.DOWN: character.gotoAndStop(1); movingDown=false;  moving = 1; break;
     case Keyboard.UP: character.gotoAndStop(3);movingUp=false; moving = 2; break;
     case Keyboard.LEFT: character.gotoAndStop(5);movingLeft=false;  moving = 3; break;
     case Keyboard.RIGHT: character.gotoAndStop(7);movingRight=false;  moving = 4; break;   
     case Keyboard.SPACE: handleAttack(); break;      
   }       
} 

 function handleAttack():void
 {          
    switch (moving)
      {
        case 1: character.gotoAndStop(9); movingDown = false;   break;      //down
        case 2: character.gotoAndStop(10); movingUp = false;  break;        //up
        case 3: character.gotoAndStop(11); movingLeft = false;  break;      //left  attacks
        case 4: character.gotoAndStop(12); movingRight = false;  break;     //right
      }
}    

function MainLoop(e:Event):void
{

 switch (true) 
   {
     case movingDown: character.gotoAndStop(2); character.y+=4.5; break; 
     case movingUp: character.gotoAndStop(4); character.y-=4.5; break;
     case movingLeft: character.gotoAndStop(6); character.x-=4.5; break;
     case movingRight: character.gotoAndStop(8); character.x+=4.5; break; 
   } 

}
```

Comment: hrm, perhaps you're missing the 'case Keyboard.SPACE' in the onKeyRelease() handler?

Comment: I've tried this before but it still produces the same result.  Is my syntax or structure incorrect?  I'm still very new to actionscript. I've added the keySPACE: handleAttack(); under the keyUp handler, but nothing changes.  Do I need boolean triggers for each attack direction or is my approach simply incorrect?

Comment: Is it possible to remove the function call under the keyUp handler? for example:  under keyUp I would have:

Comment: case: Keyboard.SPACE: remove handleAttack(); break;

Comment: I know that the syntax isn't correct for the above line, but I've tried everything I can possibly imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am kinda new myself but i think it's because both onKeyPress() and onKeyRelease() point to the same function handleAttack() and as such point to the same frame even when you release. Try making two seperate attack functions for each one.

e.g
attackPressed() for onKeyPress()

```
function attackPressed():void
{          
    switch (moving)
    {
        case 1: character.gotoAndStop(9); movingDown = false;   break;      
        case 2: character.gotoAndStop(10); movingUp = false;  break;       
        case 3: character.gotoAndStop(11); movingLeft = false;  break;     
        case 4: character.gotoAndStop(12); movingRight = false;  break;     
    }
}
```

and attackRelease() for onKeyRelease()

```
function attackRelease():void
{
    switch (moving)
    {
        case 1:character.gotoAndStop(1); movingDown = false;  break;
        case 2:character.gotoAndStop(3); movingUp = false; break; 
        case 3: character.gotoAndStop(5); movingLeft = false; break; 
        case 4: character.gotoAndStop(7); movingRight = false; break;
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Sb1985m.  I should have updated this question earlier, but yeah that's exactly what I did to fix it. I feel foolish for not seeing that originally.  I had been staring at the screen too long.  It was simply calling the same function on release.  Consider me ashamed.  I've only been programming for about three months.  I found programming and a love for code actually studying graphic design initially, now I going to take some more computer science classes and more specifically java classes.  I'm going to pursue a masters in web development.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow as well, do you by chance know where I would go to give you the credit for answering it since you took the time to help?

Comment: Nevemind, I believe I gave you credit for the answer, as long as it's done by simply clicking that checkmark up there beside your answer itself. Let me know if you got credit.  I only want to be fair. Thanks again.

Comment: I think i got it, actually i just started programming around 2-3 months ago as well, cause i wanted to make a game myself. Registered at stack cause i found most my answers here. Anyway good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks, you too.  Gotta love game programming.